# Compactness of the boundary of a subset

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Hausdorff spaces, $f:X\to Y$ an open onto continuous map and $\partial (U)$ is compact in $X$ for some open subset $U$ of $X$. Can we deduce that $\partial(f(U))$ is compact in $Y$? My efforts did not work...

Comment: Show your efforts please.

Answer (score 2):

It is not generaly true,

For example define $ \mathbb H=\mathbb R×\left]-1,+\infty\right[$ let $X=\mathbb H× \{0,1\}$ be the product space of the open half plane with the standard topology with $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. This is of course a Hausdorff space.

Let Y be $\mathbb R^2$ with the standard topology.

Now define $f:X \to Y$ with:
$$\begin{align}f((x,y),0)&= (x,y)\\f((x,y),1)&=(x,-y).\end{align}$$

Then $f$ is a surjective open map, and now, because $\mathbb H× \{0\}$ is open and closed in $X$:

$$\partial (\mathbb H× \{0\})=\emptyset$$
which is compact.

But $\partial f(\mathbb H×\{0\}) =\partial \mathbb H = \mathbb R × \{-1\}$

which is not compact.

Comment: @AnneBauval They’ve made some edits, and I believe it is fixed now.